# Best practice for making a popup window in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, window

In my React app, I want to create a popup window that renders a table with some data. However, I want to make it render in a separate browser window instance as opposed to a modal that is attached to the app's DOM. Most of my research has led me to third party component libraries that just render an in-DOM modal just in different ways. What is the best way to create my desired effect, where clicking the "Open" button creates a new browser window instance that renders the table component?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?  I would like to open a component in an independent window and share state with the main react application.

Answer (score 0):

hmm.. maybe try the window.open() syntax

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open